# How do you use .get() with a multiframe shopping cart in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, shopping-cart, nameerror, frames

In this code. I want display the information from the frame I hit the Buy button on. I'm sure it is a simple solution but it has eluded me. I've been going through google and stack overflow with no solution yet.

I tried making the NewFrame global but that just does the last one made.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


FrameNum = 1
ItemCount = 1

def combine_funcs(*funcs):

    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)

    return combined_func


def place_order():

    global ItemCount

    Product = Product_Box.get()

    Label(root, text="Your Purchase of " + str(Product) + " Placed").grid(row=1, column=3, stick="w")
    ItemCount += 1


def create_frame():

    global FrameNum

    NewFrame = LabelFrame(root,name=("newframe"+str(FrameNum)), text=("Item "+str(FrameNum)),width=100, height=100)
    NewFrame.grid(row=FrameNum, column=0)

    Product_Lab = Label(NewFrame, text="Product").grid(row=0, column=0)

    Qty_Lab = Label(NewFrame, text="Qty").grid(row=0, column=1)

    Price_Lab = Label(NewFrame, text="Price").grid(row=0, column=2)


    # Entry Boxes

    Product_Box = Entry(NewFrame, width=10).grid(row=1, column=0)

    Qty_Box = Entry(NewFrame, width=12).grid(row=1, column=1)

    Price_box = Entry(NewFrame, width=6).grid(row=1, column=2)



    Remove_Bet_Button = Button(NewFrame, text="Del", command=NewFrame.destroy).grid(row=3, column=2)

    Buy_Button = Button(NewFrame, text="Buy", command=combine_funcs(place_order, NewFrame.destroy)).grid(row=3, column=0)

    FrameNum += 1


framebutton = Button(root, text="Frame", command=create_frame).grid(row=0, column = 3, stick ="n")


root.mainloop()
```

I get this error when hitting the Buy button. (with or without information entered into the boxes from that frame)

```
NameError: name 'Product_Box' is not defined
```

Comment: you  have common mistake - `command=` needs function's name without `()`  and arguments - it is called `Callback`. If you want to assign function with arguments then you may use `lambda`. `command=lambad:combine_funcs(place_order, NewFrame.destroy)`

Comment: you have another common mistake - `variable = tk.Widget().grid()` assigns `None` to `variable` because `grid()`/`pack()`/`place()` returns `None`. You have to do it in two steps `variable = tk.Widget()` and `varaible.grid()`

Comment: `Product_Box` is local variable created in `create_frame()` - to access it in other functions you have to assign to global variable - so you need add `global Product_Box` in `create_frame()`

Comment: there is good rule: `lower_case_names` for variables - i.e `product_box` - because it helps to recognize normal variable and class name (like `Entry`, `Button`). More in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Product_Box` is local variable created in `create_frame()` - to access it in other functions you have to assign to `global` variable - so you need add `global Product_Box` in `create_frame()`

But there is other problem:

`variable = tk.Widget().grid()` assigns `None` to `variable` because `grid()`/`pack()`/`place()` returns `None`. You have to do it in two steps `variable = tk.Widget()` and `varaible.grid()`.

```
Product_Lab = Label(NewFrame, text="Product")
Product_Lab.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

And now code works but later you will have the same problem with other variables.

---

Full working code with other changes

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def place_order(product_box, qty_box, price_box, new_frame):
    global item_count
    global label
    
    product = product_box.get()
    qty = int(qty_box.get())
    price = int(price_box.get())
    
    total = qty * price

    if not label:    
        label = tk.Label(root)
        label.grid(row=1, column=3, stick="w")
        
    # replace text
    #label['text'] = f"Your Purchase of {product} Placed. (Qty: {qty}, Price: {price}, Total: {total})"
    
    # or append in new line 
    if len(label['text']) > 0:
        label['text'] += "\n"
    label['text'] += f"Your Purchase of {product} Placed. (Qty: {qty}, Price: {price}, Total: {total})"
    
    item_count += 1

    new_frame.destroy()

def create_frame():
    global frame_number
    
    new_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, name=f"newframe {frame_number}", text=f"Item {frame_number}", width=100, height=100)
    new_frame.grid(row=frame_number, column=0)

    tk.Label(new_frame, text="Product").grid(row=0, column=0)
    tk.Label(new_frame, text="Qty").grid(row=0, column=1)
    tk.Label(new_frame, text="Price").grid(row=0, column=2)

    # Entry Boxes

    product_box = tk.Entry(new_frame, width=10)
    product_box.grid(row=1, column=0)

    qty_box = tk.Entry(new_frame, width=12)
    qty_box.grid(row=1, column=1)

    price_box = tk.Entry(new_frame, width=6)
    price_box.grid(row=1, column=2)

    tk.Button(new_frame, text="Del", command=new_frame.destroy).grid(row=3, column=2)
    tk.Button(new_frame, text="Buy", command=lambda:place_order(product_box, qty_box, price_box, new_frame)).grid(row=3, column=0)

    frame_number += 1

# --- main ---

frame_number = 1
item_count = 1

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root, text="Frame", command=create_frame).grid(row=0, column=3, stick="n")
label = None  # it will add later but only once

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I will keep working on making my code more clean and read up on it. When trying to run this code it still seems to ONLY take information from the last frame that is added. For example if I create 5 frames and then enter data into Frame 3 and click the buy button.  I get this error. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' However if the buy button is hit in any frame it will use the frame 5 inputs. So in this example how would we get the Frame 3 buy button to get the frame 3 data?

Comment: I didn't check it but every button will need run function with arguments - to get values from correct widgets. At thsi moment all frames uses the same globla variables to all of them get values from the same widgets.

Comment: I modify code in answer - now button send widgets to function as arguments so every button use different widgets and it calculate different values..

Comment: Right. That's what I can't figure out. I had tried using globals before with the same result that we have here. Again I appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks @Furas. I'll keep getting the code in a better format. You're a saint.

Comment: I added code which appends text to label so it shows all purchases